# Web app ? introducing a pay as you use model. How to?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have a very nice web app (HTML5, javascript,CSS) running on my website. 
It's free to use and people use it (as proved by the google analytics)

I want to add some advanced functionality and get users who want to use the advanced functionality to pay for it.

These days, what's the common way of achieving this ?

For instance, I could send the user who has paid a key (some text) to unleash the advanced functionality by entering in a text box. Or I could have a 'hidden' url which I would give just to that user.

Those are probably weak solutions and easy to crack.

I can think of many ideas but I'd rather ask since I am sure there are standard ways of doing this. 
Thanks

Comment: This is no different to any form of user authorization. Authentication and authorization libraries and frameworks are available in a number of languages and application-stacks, if you do not want to roll your own. If you want recommendations, it may be helpful to tell people what server-side systems you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want recurring payments (like they have to pay x amount every month), there are plenty of sites to help you with that. My company uses [Chargify](http://chargify.com/), but there's also [Spreedly](https://spreedly.com/), [Cheddar Getter](https://cheddargetter.com/), and much more.

These basically handle the billing for you, and you can set up web hooks (pages that will be called with a POST request) on changes, like a new subscription or when a subscription expires. There are also usually good APIs to retrieve users, subscriptions, etc.

If you want to manage the payments yourself, but want only specific users to have access to those features, why not just add a flag to your user's table, and use that flag to determine if they have access to the features? You can then modify the flag yourself as you see fit when a user pays you.

Comment: Thanks. I am not concerned about how to get paid. I am more interested on how to ensure that only users who paid are to get the web app. I will edit my question to reflect that.